# Get latest record from second table

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I am getting all employee list with first salary, I want all employee with latest salary credited.

**Employee-Table**

```
emp_id | emp_name
-------|--------- 
101    | Andrew
102    | John
103    | Alex
```

**Salary-Table**

```
sal_id | emp_id | month                 | salary
-------|--------|-----------------------|-------
201    | 101    | 1st jan 2018          | 10000
202    | 101    | 1st feb 2018          | 20000
203    | 101    | 1st march2018         | 30000
204    | 102    | 1st jan 2018          | 10000
205    | 102    | 1st feb 2018          | 20000
206    | 102    | 1st march2018         | 30000
207    | 103    | 1st jan 2018          | 10000
208    | 103    | 1st feb 2018          | 20000
209    | 103    | 1st march2018         | 30000
```

I want to fetch all employees list with latest month salary only.
(all employee with march salary)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What have you tried? Provide some queries you tried already...

Comment: You need to show us what you've tried and where you're stuck. You currently not even asking a question, but rather giving us an assignment, which isn't really how this site works.

Comment: SELECT *

FROM `employee` 
 
LEFT  JOIN `employee` ON `employee`.`emp_id` = `salary`.`emp_id` 

GROUP BY `employee`.`emp_id`
ORDER BY `employee`.`emp_id` DESC

Comment: Edit your question to include all relevant information (like your attempts) instead of posting it in comments. Also include what output you're getting and what the expected output should be.

Answer (score 0):

This code should work :

```
<?php

    $date = date('F Y');

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM Employee-table et 
            INNER JOIN Salary-Table st ON et.emp_id = st.emp_id 
            WHERE st.month LIKE '%$date%'";
```

Comment: I am getting all employee list with first salary,after left join ,  I want all employee with latest salary credited.

Comment: are you kidding me ?

Comment: Last salary of the last month ?

Comment: yes I want employee list with column of latest salary only, But I am getting their first salary

Answer (score 0):

```
$date = date('F Y');

$saleries = $this->db->select('e.*, s.salary')
->join('Salary-Table s','s.emp_id = e.emp_id')
->like($date, 'match')
//order by the month and the group by emp id to give you the latest
->order_by('s.month', 'asc')
->group_by('e.emp_id')
//return results as an array of arrays
->get('Employee-table e')->result_array();
```

https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/query_builder.html

Comment: It the dates are written like the OP's example: `1st feb 2018`, ordering by `s.month` won't work as expected.

Comment: for latest salary or month  I have to use 
->order_by('s.month', 'DESC ')   But even after using if I am getting first salary not latest one